# I want to combined two SQL queries into one

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two SQL queries that I would like to combined into one, if its possible. The fist is to get information about a shop order and the second is to get revision information from all previous records with the same shop_order_id.

The first query:

```
SELECT so.shop_order_id, so.shop_order_suffix, so.status, so.mfg_method, so.description
  FROM shop_order so
  WHERE so.shop_order_id = 'ZZ1810C'
    AND so.shop_order_suffix = '000';`
```

The second query:

```
SELECT so.user_att27, so.user_att28 
  FROM shop_order so
  WHERE so.shop_order_id LIKE 'ZZ1810C%'
  ORDER BY shop_order_suffix DESC;`
```

Is it possible to combined them so that they run at one time and if so how would i got about doing it?

Comment: I will in 5 min. I can't at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a JOIN :

```
    SELECT so.shop_order_id, so.shop_order_suffix, so.status, so.mfg_method, so.description,  so2.user_att27, so2.user_att28
    FROM shop_order so 
    JOIN shop_order so2 ON so2.shop_order_id LIKE 'ZZ1810C%'
    WHERE so.shop_order_id = 'ZZ1810C' AND so.shop_order_suffix = '000'
    ORDER BY shop_order_suffix DESC;
```

Comment: thank you, I did not think to use a `LIKE` in the `ON` statement

Answer (score 0):

What do you want the results to be?  An example would be helpful.

The following combines the two conditions:

```
SELECT so.shop_order_id, so.shop_order_suffix, so.status, so.mfg_method,
      so.description, so.user_att27, so.user_att28
FROM shop_order so
WHERE so.shop_order_id LIKE 'ZZ1810C%'
ORDER BY shop_order_suffix DESC;
```

This will list all the rows for the shop order, with the initial information duplicated on each row.  The additional fields tell you about the revisions.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the intent of the second query is to get all previous records with the SAME shop_order_id, but the second query filters on shop_order_ids that START WITH the provided text, as specified by the LIKE clause.

If the intent is to include all of these, the two queries are from the same table, so just grab the union of all columns for all such entries. I'd order by shop_order_id so that the one without any additional suffix text shows up first:

SELECT so.shop_order_id, so.shop_order_suffix, so.status, so.mfg_method, so.description, so.user_att27, so.user_attr28 FROM shop_order so WHERE so.shop_order_id LIKE 'ZZ1810C%' AND so.shop_order_suffix='000' ORDER BY so.shop_order_id DESC;

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. We have not imported much data to our new server so i only have limited information to test with. I used `so.shop_order_id LIKE 'ZZ1810%'` to try to get multiple records so expanded the data I was searching. Then i just copied the query directly to here.